# C# MVVM Prism questions

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I try to understand C# prism framework, and make a little project. I meet some problem with misunderstanding Prism concept. I will explain what i want to do, what i try, my code:

I want to make a simple application like a test with 5 random question. You select difficult of test after you press start. On the same window your page is change with first question. Select right answer , next and you go on the second page with second question. From the second question you have 2 buttons(prev and next) , next next next, finish and you have a message like "you got x/5 points".
I have a similar aplication but the framework use is Caliburn.
[First Application](https://github.com/WiDuAlK12/CSharp-WPF-MVVM/tree/master/Application/WPFUI)
I want to put all questions in xaml file now.

What i try:
I follow documentation, youtube tutorials for 2 days.
I create 2 folders: View and ViewModel. Create MainPage.xaml like a window in View and in ViewModel i create MainPageViewModel, in file MainPage.cs i create one instance like:

```
MainPageViewModel main = new MainPageViewModel();
```

After this i create a button i test the button and work.
Now I want to create a Page to connect with MainPageViewModel window. In the page i want to create another button and i want to check if is work. But this is the step how can't create.

After follow few tutorials, i can't make this. Not work to connect on the xaml file MainPageViewModel.

MainPage:

```
    <Window x:Class="Aplicatie2._0.View.MainPage"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Aplicatie2._0.View"
        prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"
        
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="{Binding Title}" Height="450" Width="800">
        <Window.DataContext>
                
        </Window.DataContext>
        <Grid>
                
    </Grid>
</Window>
Error MC3063: Property 'DataContext' does not have a value. Line 14 Position 30.
```

MainPageViewModel:

```
using Prism.Mvvm;
using Prism.Navigation;
using Prism.Commands;

namespace Aplicatie2._0.ViewModel
{
        class MainPageViewModel : BindableBase
        {
                private string _Title = "Test";
                public string Title
                {
                        get
                        {
                                return _Title;
                        }
                        set
                        {
                                SetProperty(ref _Title, value);
                        }
                }
        }
}
```

App.xaml:

```
    <prism:PrismApplication x:Class="Aplicatie2._0.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Aplicatie2._0">
        <Application.Resources>

        </Application.Resources>
</prism:PrismApplication>
```

App.xaml.cs:

```
using Prism.Modularity;
using Prism.Ioc;
using System.Windows;
using System.ComponentModel;
using Prism.Unity;
using Aplicatie2._0.View;

namespace Aplicatie2._0
{
        public partial class App  : PrismApplication
        {
                protected override Window CreateShell()
                {
                        return Container.Resolve<MainPage>();
                }

                protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
                {
                        containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<MainPage>("MainPage");
                }

        }
}
```

1)How can i create multiple page and how can connect with main window?(If i call page1 i want to be clear, to create button and Radiobutton on the page)
2)How can i connect ViewModel file with View file on xaml, without create instance?
3)How can i create one question in xaml like:

```
Question: This is first question
[] Answer1
[] Answer2
[] Answer3
```

If you can to give me an example it's perfect, but make it simple.

Comment: "Property 'DataContext' does not have a value."

Comment: @RobertHarvey right now i solve that  haha, but how can i connect page.xaml with mainWindow.xaml?

Comment: The Prism Documentation for WPF is [here](https://prismlibrary.com/docs/wpf/introduction.html).  You should read that, in its entirety.  Then read it again.  When you're done reading it the second time, download the [Prism WPF Samples](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism-Samples-Wpf) and go through all of them, in order.  Make sure you completely understand each sample before you go onto the next.

Comment: That is how I learned Prism.